# WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I'm using WSO2 API Manager 1.6 & WSO2 BAM 2.4.1. I was able to successfully configure API Manager with BAM. It worked fine and I was able to get the analytics. But due to security reasons I had to change default the admin password of the API Manager which was admin/admin. Since I changed the password in AM I get the following error while running the API Manager with BAM. I think now the BAM is not reachable.

```
[2015-11-03 10:15:59,731]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2701
[2015-11-03 10:16:47,556]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-2702
```

Is there a place to change the password in BAM as well respective to the API Manager so that password changes on AM will reflect on BAM as well? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a place to change the password in BAM as well? How can I fix
>   this?

You can do it through UI

```
Configure > Users and Roles > Change Password
```

Comment: No I mean relevant to API Manager. Please read the full question